# Why is my email being sent out from an Unknown Sender?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email

The from portion of the email is saying: `From: UnknownSender@UnknownDomain`

Could it have to do with this line my in mailer file?

```
  default :from => "DreamStill"
```

I'm using the SendGrid add on for Heroku. It seems that DreamStill showed up for some addresses, and unknown sender for others.

Comment: That does not look like a valid From address.

Comment: so? it showed up as `From:DreamStill` for some people

Comment: I think what Phrogz is saying is that the display of the "from" field is (a) up to the mail client displaying it (Outlook, Gmail, etc.), and (b) that "DreamStill" is not a valid email address, and therefore in some clients will show up as "UnknownSender@UnknownDomain" - since it cannot determine from the text "DreamSill", where the email came from

Comment: ahh ok... it's very strange though because I spoke with two people, both with aol accounts, one got DreamStill, the other got unknown sender... so i guess it is account specific...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify a valid email address for your "from" field, such as:

```
:from => "DreamStill <justin@dreamstill.com>"
```

The way it's being displayed when received by users may very well be dependent on what application is displaying the email, such as Outlook, Gmail, etc.

There's also a number of hurdles, like spam filters, anti-virus scanners, services such as MessageLabs, that email goes through these days. Any one of these could be causing it. Basically, specify a valid email address for the "from" field, and try again.

Comment: yeah, my problem is that I want it to say `From:DreamStill`. If I specify an actual email address like `justin@dreamstill.com` then it will display `justin` in the inbox before the email is clicked. I guess I need a DreamStill@DreamStill.com email address then

Comment: Yeah. I think the point is, you can't control how the receiving end will display it, so you shouldn't try too hard. One client will display it one way, and another will display it another way. You'll probably have to pick something you're happy with, and just roll with it.

Comment: Phrogz has a good idea in his answer below - putting the name followed by the email in brackets should work (updated my answer). If that works, I almost feel like Phrogz should get credit for the correct answer.

Comment: Editing the accepted answer to include additional details from other answers is encouraged on Stack Overflow. I'm happy to let you have the credit, and have deleted my answer.